# How to remove selection from ListView when not in focus in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have multiple ListViews and ListBoxes in my WPF UserControl. I want to remove selected items from them whenever they are not in focus.

I have tried the following.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

The above method makes no difference.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="false">
             <Setter Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False"/>
         </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

This method removes selection only when one item is selected. If SelectionMode="Extended", this method doesn't work.

Comment: Consider writing an attached behavior to do this. You will have much more control than with a trigger.

Comment: Do you want your selection to be removed and then re-applied as usercontrol gets focus? Or just removed?

Comment: @netaholic I want to remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item}"  
          FocusLost="your ICommand implementation/>
```

In code behind in your Command on FocusLost :

```
try { 
  Items.Remove(Item); 
} catch (Exception ex) { 
  ...
}
```

Should work for you I guess.

Comment: That's what I did. But I was wondering if I could apply a common style for all the controls.

Comment: What do you mean by common style? If answer is correct, please mark it as answer (on the left side)

Comment: This is the straight forward approach. I have mentioned in my question that I have multiple ListViews and ListBoxes. I wanted to know if I could apply a common style to all of these controls to achieve the functionality I required.

Comment: Just generalize your focuslost processing